# Python checking if variable is higher than it was last loop

Tags: python

just getting started in Python and I'm writing a program that checks for alerts, basically I need it to keep track of a number and if the next loop that number is higher, then do stuff.

```
def code():
yellowCount = 0
orangeCount = 0
redCount = 0
blueCount = 0

print ("----------------------------------------")
print ("Running check on ")
# do your stuff
for line in open(txtFiles[0]):
    if 'details_YELLOW' in line:
        yellowCount = yellowCount + 1
    elif 'details_ORANGE' in line:
        orangeCount = orangeCount + 1
    elif 'details_RED' in line:
        redCount = redCount + 1
        toaster.show_toast("xxxxx","Red alert detected on ")

    elif 'details_BLUE' in line:
        blueCount = blueCount + 1
print (str(yellowCount) + " Yellow alerts")
print (str(orangeCount) + " Orange alerts")
print (str(redCount) + " Red alerts")
print (str(blueCount) + " Blue alerts")
```

There's a code excerpt, what's the best way to go about this? Global variables? Basically I only want to alert if there's a NEW alert, not notify for every single alert detected every time the code runs.

Example of Code Output

```
==================
Downloading Alerts
==================
----------------------------------------
Running check on 
0 Yellow alerts
0 Orange alerts
0 Red alerts
0 Blue alerts
----------------------------------------
Running check on 
0 Yellow alerts
1 Orange alerts
0 Red alerts
0 Blue alerts
```

So I want to execute code only if the orange alerts goes to 2 on the second for example

Comment: "Global variables? B": no: just keep an extra variable around that has the previous value: `prev_redCount` could work. Compare that to `redCount` every iteration, and assign it the value of `redCount` at the end of the loop body.

Comment: Note: Python idiom doesn't use (lower) camelCase for variable names, but snake_case. `red_count` is more Python-style as a variable name.

Comment: Of course, the next stage Python idiom is to use a mapping type like a `dict` for the various counters, or even [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). But that's for the iteration of your program.

Comment: Last Python idiom thing (sorry): Replace `print (str(yellowCount) + " Yellow alerts")` by `print (yellowCount, "Yellow alerts")`. Let `print()` do the formatting/stringifying of `yellowCount` for you.

Comment: Thanks guys :) My PHP is showing with the camelCase obviously haha

Answer (score 0):

This very easy to do, all you need to do is to keep a variable outside the for loop that will keep track of the previous value:

```
prev_count = 0
for ... :
    count = ...
    if prev_count < count:
        #do stuff
    prev_count = count
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the integer value doesn't remember its history, so you do it with various  work-arounds:

- keep a flag `yellow_changed = False`. If the condition satisfied, change it to `True`. However, you have to reset them to `False`, at the start of every iteration
- Do the stuff directly:

  ```
  if 'details_YELLOW' in line:
     # yellowCount = yellowCount + 1
     do_the_yellow_stuff()
  ```
- keep a list of the values. At every iteration `yellow_values.append(yellowCount)` and then check if `yellowCount[-1] > yellowCount[-2]`